# sphinx returns less matches in comparison a sql like search

Tags: sphinx

im using Sphinx to make searchs in my web, but i have a thing, when i search in phpmyadmin using

```
LIKE '%19.628%'
```

returns the data that im looking for (8 matches), but when i use the sphinx returns less matches (3 matches) in comparison a sql LIKE search.

here the PHP code

```
$sp->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
$sp->SetArrayResult(true);
$sp->SetLimits(0,1000000);
$results = $sp->Query($query, 'data_base');
```

why?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx doesn't use the wildcard in quite the same way MySQL does. Here's a couple reasons you may not be getting the results you want;

- In your example, MySQL will evaluate the entire value in that field. However, Sphinx may see the string `19.628` somewhat differently. If you are using the default [phrase boundary](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/conf-phrase-boundary.html), then Sphinx will break up that string up into 2 words, potentially resulting in different results.
- What exactly is the value of `$query`? I would suspect that it would be something along the lines of '*19.628*'. If you don't have [star syntax](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-enable-star) enabled, you may not get the results you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help, im using the defautl phrase_boundary, the `$query`, contains only 19.628, the star_syntax, wasnt enabled. i change the config file adding your suggestions and the issue continues, here is part of my config file:

Comment: `phrase_boundary_step = 100` `phrase_boundary = ., ?, !, U+2026` `enable_star = 1`, im thinking that the issue has the origin in the sql_query, cause im using this `SELECT * FROM juris`, can be?

Comment: The defualt phrase_boundary is empty. And besides it only affects word positions stored index, to stop explicit phrase searches from matching  acorss boundaries. It doesnt affect the query, chars in phrase_boundary dont have any special meaning in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that sphinx indexes whole words by default, so wont even get part-word matches unless explicitly enable it with infix/prefix indexing - with or without enable_star.

A sphinx query of `19.628` will just look for the whole words `19` and `628` anywhere in the document. Asumming `.` isn't in your charset_table of course!

In fact you even enable `Any` mode. So it looks for just one of the words.

So to get the same documents matching, would need to use `Extended` mode. Surround the query in `"` to get phrase matches. And use `*` in place of the `%`.

```
$cl->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$cl->Query('"%19.628%"',$index);
```

For the index setting, you dont want `.` in `phrase_boundary` (because you want to use phrase searching), you need to enable part word matching - with `min_infix_len`, because want `*` at beginning and end of words (if using `enable_star=1`).

You can choose if you want `.` in charset_table or not. For this query it shouldn't matter much.

(tangental, but your really high $limit wont actully apply, setLimits has a third $max_matches param, which sets the highest $offset+$limit you can use - defaults to 1000)